# Returning distinct characters in combined Strings

Tags: java, strings

I am trying to return distinct characters from the combination of 2 `String`s. The following is my solution which seems to work based on my tests.

Is there a more efficient way of going about this? I have converted the strings to arrays, to sets, to a `StringBuilder` and back to a `String`. I'm wondering if I have overcomplicated something which could have been resolved a lot simpler.

```
public String longest (String s1, String s2) {

    String[] s1Arr = s1.split("");
    String[] s2Arr = s2.split("");

    Set<String> arr1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(s1Arr));
    Set<String> arr2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(s2Arr));

    arr1.addAll(arr2);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Iterator<String> it = arr1.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()){
        String element = it.next();
        sb.append(element);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: It's a bit odd that you return the result as a `String`, when the order of entries is arbitrary. What is the use case for this code?

Comment: `arr2` is not needed since you can directly add the second list to the first set: `arr1.addAll(Arrays.asList(s2Arr));` also I agree with @200_success: the output is most likely more useful if you order  the result before converting it back to a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What comes to performance, you can improve it significantly:

```
public static String getDistinctCharString(String s1, String s2) {
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>(s1.length() + s2.length());

    char[] chars1 = s1.toCharArray();
    char[] chars2 = s2.toCharArray();

    for (char c : chars1) {
        set.add(c);
    }

    for (char c : chars2) {
        set.add(c);
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(set.size());

    for (char c : set) {
        sb.append(c);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

The point is that you deal with characters rather than substrings of length 1.

My [demonstration](https://gist.github.com/coderodde/bc25e380be628a67c7c5f4edbd409ecd) gives me the following output:

```
longest() in 2558 ms.
getDistinctCharString() in 342 ms.
Algorithms agree: true
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: if you are setting `HashSet` size, you should do it right.

Answer (score 2):

With Java8, this problem can be solved somewhat easily:

```
public static String java8Version(
        final String s1,
        final String s2) {
    ////
    return IntStream.concat(s1.chars(), s2.chars()).distinct()
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
            .toString();
}
```

Below approximated times, for shorter input-strings coderodde's solution has the upper hand, for larger strings the IntStream version seems to be preferable:

Benchmark for two strings of length n, seeds for randoms: 14536426262341L and 536475869798457L (number of distinct characters are 1968, 17254, 62399 and 65536):
(Ievgen Anikushyn's version is without the sorted() call, other versions are 1:1 copied)

```
Benchmark                  (n)  Mode  Cnt        Score        Error  Units
getDistinctCharString     1000  avgt   25      142.482 ±      4.349  us/op
getDistinctCharString    10000  avgt   25     1184.946 ±     43.352  us/op
getDistinctCharString   100000  avgt   25    17690.026 ±   1511.287  us/op
getDistinctCharString  1000000  avgt   25   223346.656 ±   8074.609  us/op
java8Version              1000  avgt   25      151.340 ±      4.785  us/op
java8Version             10000  avgt   25     1485.053 ±     43.114  us/op
java8Version            100000  avgt   25    13637.576 ±    488.871  us/op
java8Version           1000000  avgt   25   159596.194 ±   4782.828  us/op
java8IevgenAnikushyn      1000  avgt   25      231.984 ±      5.321  us/op
java8IevgenAnikushyn     10000  avgt   25     2280.803 ±     99.742  us/op
java8IevgenAnikushyn    100000  avgt   25    31600.095 ±    851.614  us/op
java8IevgenAnikushyn   1000000  avgt   25   341541.386 ±   7357.557  us/op
longest                   1000  avgt   25      306.865 ±      9.798  us/op
longest                  10000  avgt   25     3510.012 ±    116.975  us/op
longest                 100000  avgt   25    65478.694 ±   1832.871  us/op
longest                1000000  avgt   25  1854812.781 ± 473216.482  us/op
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 8. For any number of strings:

```
public static String getDistinctCharString(String... strings) {
        return Stream.of(strings)
                .map(String::chars)
                .flatMap(intStream -> intStream.mapToObj(charCode -> new String(new char[]{(char) charCode})))
                .distinct()
                .sorted()
                .collect(joining());
    }

Elapsed time: 141 ms
```

Sorted is optional. Or a bit refactored version:

```
public static String getDistinctCharString(String... strings) {
        return Stream.of(strings)
                .map(String::chars)
                .flatMap(intStream -> intStream.mapToObj(charCode -> (char) charCode))
                .distinct()
                .sorted()
                .map(character -> new String(new char[]{character}))
                .collect(joining());
    }
Elapsed time: 137 ms
```